# C# - Cannot put private void method with parameters in override ToString method

Tags: c#

I've been tasked to create a private void method, here is a code snippet of the private void method from the constructor class:

```html
private void CalculateBreakEven(string companyName, decimal sellingPrice, decimal fixedOverHead, decimal adminSalaries, decimal rawMaterialsPercent, decimal laborCostPercent)
        {
            decimal totalVariableCost = rawMaterialsPercent + laborCostPercent;
            decimal contributionMargin = sellingPrice * totalVariableCost;
            decimal breakEvenUnits = Math.Ceiling((fixedOverHead + adminSalaries) / contributionMargin);
            decimal breakEvenDollars = breakEvenUnits * sellingPrice;
            WriteLine("Break Even units are: ", breakEvenUnits);
            WriteLine("Break Even sales are: ", breakEvenDollars);
            
        }
```

This code appears not to work with my ToString method...

```html
        public override string ToString()
        {
            
            return string.Format("Selling price: {0:C}\nFixed overhead costs: {1:C}\nFixed cost administrative salaries: {2:C}\nRaw material percent of selling price: {3:C}\nLabor cost percent of selling price: {4:C}\n", CalculateBreakEven(string companyName, decimal sellingPrice, decimal fixedOverHead, decimal adminSalaries, decimal rawMaterialsPercent, decimal laborCostPercent).ToString());
        }
```

I get errors saying that I need to add the parameters (string companyName, decimal sellingPrice, decimal fixedOverHead, decimal adminSalaries, decimal rawMaterialsPercent, decimal laborCostPercent) to CalculateBreakEven()l in ToString method.

I tried and added the parameters and removed string/decimal from it but it wouldn't do the calculations when I run the program... How do I fix?

Comment: You don't need to pass parameter types when calling method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your ToString implementation.

1. Your format string takes 5 inputs, `{0:C}` through `{4:C}` but you only provide one "value", the result of your `CalculateBreakEven` function. As a smaller, easier to read example, you might call `string.Format` like `string.Format("A:{0} B:{1} C:{2} D:{3} E:{4}", "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth");` but you're calling it like `string.Format("A:{0} B:{1} C:{2} D:{3} E:{4}", "first");` so there are no values given for `{1}` through `{4}`.
2. Your `CalculateBreakEven` function has a return type of `void`. You cannot call `ToString()`, or any other method on `void`.
3. When you call `CalculateBreakEven` you must somehow supply values to its parameters. Those could be hard-coded, like `CalculateBreakEven("Company Name", 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` or they could be variables like `CalculateBreakEven(coName, sellPrice, overHead, salaries, rawMaterialsPct, laborCostPct)` but then those variables need to be defined somewhere and given values.

Comment: I updated the code and everything seems to work now, but the calculations for Total Variable Percent, Break Even units and Break even sales seems wrong by a few digits...

In CalculateBreakEven

 [enter image description here][1]

The output I get from running the program is:
Total Fixed costs: 180,000 <- correct
Total variable percent: $0.75 <- incorrect, should be $0.70
Break even units: 16,000 < incorrect, should be 17143

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRsws.png

Is my mathimatics wrong?

Comment: Without knowing your requirements it would be hard to say exactly what's wrong, but comments are not the right place to ask that. It should be posted as a new question with the necessary context to help someone answer. If this answer resolved your original question, please mark it as accepted.